# Using different permission decorators in the same class based view in django

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I recently switched to class-based views in my Django app and want to use them as elegantly as possible. In the app, I have a comment system and, if permissions are matched, admins should be able to delete and/or publish/unpublish a comment. I wrote a `RedirectView` for that, including both functionality:

```
class CommentChangeView(RedirectView, SingleObjectMixin):
    """
    A redirection that acts on a Comment. The url parameter
    "action" is taken as a class function and executed.
    """

    model = Comment


    def get_redirect_url(self, pk):
        """
        Redirect to the article page, always.
        """
        return reverse('post', args=(self.object.post.slug,))


    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Here, it is decided what to execute.
        """

        self.object = self.get_object()
        func = getattr(self, kwargs.pop('action', None), None)

        if callable(func):
            func()

        return super(CommentChangeView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

    @method_decorator(permission_required('blog.delete_comment'))
    def delete(self):
        """
        Delete the comment
        """

        self.object.delete()
        messages.success(self.request, 'Comment deleted.')

    @method_decorator(permission_required('blog.change_comment'))
    def toggle_publish(self):
        """
        Toggle its publication state
        """

        self.object.published = not self.object.published
        self.object.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'Comment toggled.')
```

Now the thing is, I want the two actions to have different permissions - hence the different decorators. Usually, the `dispatch` function is decorated. The code above doesn't work, I am getting a `TypeError`. Without the decorators, it works perfectly.

How would I implement this case? Or should I separate the views for deletion and publication?

---

Here is the StackTrace of the `TypeError`:

```
Internal Server Error: /comment/toggle_publish/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/***/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/***/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/***/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 86, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/***/blog/blog/views.py", line 186, in get
    func()
  File "/***/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: _wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: You should post the traceback of the `TypeError`. *Might* help in debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bibhas pointed me into the right direction, by more closely looking at the StackTrace. I was able to get it working by introducing one additional argument for the functions. This code works now:

```
class CommentChangeView(RedirectView, SingleObjectMixin):
    """
    A redirection that acts on a Comment. The url parameter
    "action" is taken as a class function and executed. It therefore
    combines the delete and publish_comment functions (and, later, possibly)
    more.
    """

    model = Comment


    def get_redirect_url(self, pk):
        """
        Redirect to the article page, always.
        """
        return reverse('post', args=(self.object.post.slug,))


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Here, it is decided what to execute.
        """

        self.object = self.get_object()
        func = getattr(self, kwargs.pop('action', None), None)

        if callable(func):
            func(request)

        return super(CommentChangeView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    @method_decorator(permission_required('blog.delete_comment'))
    def delete(self, request):
        """
        Delete the comment
        """

        self.object.delete()
        messages.success(self.request, 'Comment deleted.')

    @method_decorator(permission_required('blog.change_comment'))
    def toggle_publish(self, request):
        """
        Toggle its publication state
        """

        self.object.published = not self.object.published
        self.object.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'Comment toggled.')
```